# How can I query Wikidata to get a list of all people in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, rest, sparql, rdf, wikidata

I would like to query like this:

> Query WikiData for all entities where the property instance of (P31) has the value human (Q5).

How do I do that using Node.js?

Searching for this on the web leads to things like [this](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Humans_born_in_New_York_City), example SPARQL queries, but I am not sure how to run those in Node.js. I see things like https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/SPARQL.js for parsing SPARQL queries, but I'm not sure how to run these queries.

Searching for a Wikidata SPARQL API gives a UI instead https://query.wikidata.org. Basically I am not sure where to start on this.

So basically my question is two parts:

1. What is the exact SPARQL query I want?
2. How do I paginate using the [Wikidata SPARQL API](https://medium.com/@fadirra/wikidata-querying-using-node-js-and-request-34dd5e6cab85)?

---

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function start() {
  const query = `SELECT * WHERE {<http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3630> <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P1376> ?o}`
  const url = `https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=${encodeURI(query)}`
  const res = await fetch(url)
  // ...
}
```

Comment: any SPARQL tutorial would make you able to write the query, especially given that the exercise already contains the identifiers ... here we go: `SELECT * WHERE {?s <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31>  <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q5>}`

Comment: And "pagination" has to be done via `limit` and `offset`, e.g. `select ... where { ... } limit 10 offset 20` would give you a chunk of size 10 starting from "position" 20. But to be honest, for proper pagination you also need `order by` which is sometimes expensive, so without it's faster but you have to hope that the triple store does something deterministic, otherwise `select ... where { ... } limit 10 offset 20 order by ...`

Comment: Try also LDF: https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/ldf

Comment: This just a parser, it does not aim to do anything more.

Answer (score 0):

This [Lib](https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/SPARQL.js) is just a parser, it does not aim to do anything more.

Other projects (that use SPARQL.js) exist that do what you need, such as:

- [fetch-sparql](https://github.com/rubensworks/fetch-sparql-endpoint.js/)
- [comunica](https://github.com/comunica/comunica)
- [sparql-http-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sparql-http-client)